# Запуск каждые сутки в 00:00

Tags: php, cron

Как верно выставить тайм в крон, для того чтобы задача выполнялась раз в сутки в 00:00 часов?

```
0 0 * * *
```

Что та подсказывает, что данная настройка неверна

Comment: https://crontab.guru/every-night-at-midnight С виду ты все правильно делаешь.

Comment: Время выставленно правильно. А в чем именно сомнения и на основе чего они появляются?